# VBA - Ignoring Hidden Worksheets - Saving Specific Worksheets as PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm learning VBA as a means to speed up some processes at my work. I have to send rooming lists to properties in PDF format generated form excel. I have the following code that works great, but I get an error message whenever one of the worksheets is hidden. I have to hide sheets often as properties change from trip to trip.

I want to PDF the Worksheets from the 4th sheet to the sheetname "Post". Whenever I hide a sheet in between these I get the following error message "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Here's the code:

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
Dim I As Integer
Dim Fname As String
Dim TabCount As Long


TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index

' Begin the loop.

For I = 4 To TabCount
Sheets(I).Activate
With ActiveSheet
Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range(" B1")
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
"C:\Users\brandon.ford\Desktop\Operation Automated\" & Fname,     
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
Next I
End Sub
```

Anyone have any ideas how to remedy this problem so the 'For I = 4 to TabCount' ignores any hidden tabs? Any help would be MUCH appreciated, I've been trying to tackle this problem for a long time and do not have much VBA knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheets.Visible` has 3 states : `xlSheetVisible, xlSheetHidden, xlSheetVeryHidden`

xlSheetVeryHidden is for hidden sheet that cannot be made visible from Excel, it won't even be in your list.

So with the test, you will avoid hidden sheets and it'll go smoothly!

Try this :

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim TabCount As Long


    TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index

    ' Begin the loop.

    For I = 4 To TabCount
        If Sheets(I).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
        Else
            With Sheets(I)
                Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range(" B1")
                .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                "C:\Users\brandon.ford\Desktop\Operation Automated\" & Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! For some reason when I run this macro, nothing happens. No error and it doesn't appear to get started as nothing loads

Comment: My bad, I forgot Sheet into the variable because I haven't used them in a long time! Corrected it! ;)

Comment: Upvoted as unlike the original code and accepted answer it doesn't activate each sheet

Comment: Ah yes, this one is quicker and a bit cleaner as it doesn't change the worksheet you're on by activating others. I've changed accepted answer although both work great!

Comment: @brettdj, I agree this code is better since it does not Activate the Sheets before checking for visibility.  Having said that, on a Q&A site, I always think it's clearer to change/add as little code as possible to answer the question at hand.  For this particular example, you would hate to give the impression that the Visible property is related to the Sheet being Activated.  Either way, the difference is minor since our code is identical aside from that point.

Answer (score 3):

With your current loop, this is best avoided by simply checking that the WorkSheet is visible before trying to export.  The Visible property contains this info.  The value should be xlSheetVisible if the sheet is visible.

Here is the full code with the check:

```
Sub SaveAllPDF()
Dim I As Integer
Dim Fname As String
Dim TabCount As Long


TabCount = Sheets("Post").Index

' Begin the loop.

For I = 4 To TabCount
Sheets(I).Activate
With ActiveSheet
    If .Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

        Fname = .Range("C15") & " " & .Range(" B1")
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\brandon.ford\Desktop\Operation Automated\" & Fname,
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    End If
End With
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked great! Thank you so much, I feel like I've been dancing around that fix for so long and couldn't quite get it right.